# Unrecognised selector error when adding UIImage to array

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, nsarray, nsdictionary

I am storing a `UIImage` in a `NSDictionary`, and then passing the `NSDictionary` at another place in the app.  gridImages is a `NSMutableArray`

```
NSDictionary *pageDict = [pageArray objectAtIndex:0];

UIImage *pageImage = [pageDict objectForKey:@"image"];

[gridImages addObject:pageImage];
```

pagedict returns

```
{
    class = is;
    image = "<UIImage: 0x14e20e10>";
    name = kaka;
    page = 64;
}
```

which presumably I do

```
UIImage *pageImage = [pageDict objectForKey:@"image"];
```

However, when I try to add that UIImage to an array, I get this error:

```
-[UIImage stringByDeletingPathExtension]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14e20e10
```

Any idea whats going on?

EDIT:

For the `NSDictionary`, I tried storing the `UIImage` as `NSData`:

```
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(textbookImage);
    [pageDict setObject:imageData forKey:@"image"];
    [pageDict setObject:textbookName forKey:@"name"];
    [pageDict setObject:page forKey:@"page"];
    [pageDict setObject:nameOfClass forKey:@"class"];
```

And the parsing it like this:

```
  NSData *imageData = [pageDict objectForKey:@"image"];
   UIImage *pageImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

But it still returns the same error

Comment: You are calling a method (`stringByDeletingPathExtension`) on `pageImage` that does not exists in the `UIImage` class.

Comment: Where am I calling that method?

Comment: [pageDict objectForKey:@"image"] is image url or image data?

Comment: @Spenciefy I don't know, you did not post the code which does, but that's what the error says.

Comment: I'm not dealing with that anywhere... Maybe it is the result of `image = "<UIImage: 0x14e20e10>";`  being stored with ""?

Comment: OK lets see a stack trace.  Also have a crack with the debugger; step through at code and examine the objects.

Comment: if there is data then you have to write [UIImage imageWithData: imagedata] and if there is Image Url then you have to write     [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageurl]];

Comment: Check if pageImage is a valid UIImage before adding it to the array. if ([pageImage isKindOfClass:[UIImage class]]) {...}

Comment: it is data... I will try storing it and parsing it as NSData

Comment: ya you have to store data in NSMutableArray and parse to next view controller.

Comment: look at edit @PradhyumanChavda

Comment: Please tell me first Are you want to pass image data and its details from one view controller to another?

Comment: No, I am actually storing a nsdictionary as a NSUserdefault, and then when I relaunch the app I need to retrieve the saved images that are part of the nsdictionary

Comment: And you have multiple images and you want to store all images,bookname and pages in user defaults. Right?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39109/discussion-between-spenciefy-and-pradhyuman-chavda)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't set `UIImage` into `NSUserDefaults` as `UIImage` is **non-property-list** object.

You better store path of image from **documents directory**.

This code will help.

**// SET Image**

```
NSString *strImagePath = //path of image from documents directory

NSMutableDictionary *dictOne = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:0];

[dictOne setObject:strImagePath forKey:@"image"];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:dictOne forKey:@"dict"];
```

**// GET image**

```
 NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"dict"];

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[dict objectForKey@"image"]];
```

**EDIT:**

```
 NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
 NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
 NSString *strImageFileName = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"yourImageFileName"];
 UIImage *image = // Your image;

 NSData *dataImage = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5f);
 /* Good image quality
        NSData *dataImage = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image); 
 */

[dataImage writeToFile:strImageFileName atomically:YES];
```

Happy coding.

Comment: how do I find the strImagePath? my image is a uiimage taken directly from the iphone camera

Comment: when you get the image then save it to the documents directory with specific file name. Then save that file name to strImagePath. got it @Spenciefy ?

Comment: Thanks, now I have the path stored in user defaults. However, when I try to add to the array `[gridImages addObject:pageImage];` i still get this error: `-[UIImage stringByDeletingPathExtension]`

Comment: What kind of object is `grindImages` ?

Comment: NSMutableArray object

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39114/discussion-between-akshit-zaveri-and-spenciefy)

Comment: the problem was in the uicollectionview I was using... it needs to be `gridImageView.image = [gridImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];` and not  `gridImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[gridImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];`. Also I used document directory; it is much faster.